# Replace BLE callbacks using Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, kotlin-coroutines

I want to use Kotlin's coroutines to handle BLE's asynchronous callbacks. Connecting to a BLE device takes a callback object, something like:

`connectToBle(Context, Boolean, GattCallback)`

The result returns asynchronously, in a method `onConnectionStateChanged` of GattCallback object. I used `suspendCoroutine<BluetoothGatt>` to implement this as detailed in the documentation [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/coroutines.md#wrapping-callbacks).

Now `onConnectionStateChanged` returns a BluetoothGatt object which I have to save as a global variable and use to call other methods such as `discoverServices` , `readCharacteristic` , `writeCharacteristic`  etc., all of which return asynchronously in different callback methods of the GattCallback object such as `onServicesDiscovered`, `onCharacteristicRead`, `onCharacteristicWrite` and so on.

Here's the code using `suspendCoroutine`:

```
suspend fun BluetoothDevice.connectToBleDevice(
    context: Context,
    autoConnect: Boolean = false
) = suspendCoroutine<BluetoothGatt?> { cont ->

    connectGatt(context, autoConnect, object : BluetoothGattCallback() {

        override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int, newState: Int) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState)
            Timber.d("onConnectionStateChange: ")
            if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) cont.resume(null) else cont.resume(gatt)
            // save gatt instance here if success
        }

        override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status)
            if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) cont.resume(null) else cont.resume(gatt)
            // return list of services if success
        }

        override fun onCharacteristicRead(
            gatt: BluetoothGatt?,
            characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic?,
            status: Int
        ) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status)
            if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) cont.resume(null) else cont.resume(gatt)
            // return read value if success
        }
    })
}
```

Methods called on the saved gatt instance:

```
    fun discoverServices() {
        gatt?.discoverServices() // result received in onServicesDiscovered
    }

    fun readCharacteristic(serviceUUID: UUID, characteristicUUID: UUID) {
        gatt?.apply {
            val characteristic =
                getService(serviceUUID).getCharacteristic(characteristicUUID)
            readCharacteristic(characteristic) // result received in onCharacteristicRead
        }
    }
```

If I want to write "sequential code" as below:

```
val gatt = connectToBle(context, false, gattCallback) // suspend until onConnectionStateChanged returns successfully
discoverServices()                                    // suspend until discoverServices returns successfully
writeCharacteristic(characteristic, valueToWrite)     // suspend until value is written successfully
val valueRead = readCharacteristic(characteristic)    // suspend until the value is read successfully
disconnect()
```

What changes do I have to make? Should I use something other than the suspendCoroutine ?

Comment: Maybe I am missing the question here but what exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: @tyczj I'd expect the GATT methods suspend until the corresponding callbacks return but I don't see that happening. The connect method suspends as expected and I get the GATT object but the rest of the methods return immediately.

Comment: Made an edit under the "sequential code" block. GATT instance will be saved inside the same class as the `suspendCoroutine` and all other methods are invoked on this instance itself. 

`onConnectionStateChange` is the callback that returns for `connectToBle` and the continuation is resumed as soon as it returns. If I want all GATT methods to be "suspending" i.e., return after their corresponding callbacks return, how should I go about it?

Comment: Due to how the API is built I dont think you will be able to accomplish that since there are multiple callbacks for the `BluetoothGattCallback`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [Kable](https://github.com/JuulLabs/kable) might fit your needs? It provides an API similar to what you've described.

For example, you can connect, write/read to/from a characteristic, then disconnect, with the following code:

```
val characteristic = characteristicOf(
    service = "00001815-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
    characteristic = "00002a56-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
)

// todo: Use scanner (provided by Kable) to obtain `peripheral`.

peripheral.apply {
    connect()
    write(characteristic, byteArrayOf(1, 2, 3))
    val valueRead: ByteArray = read(characteristic)
    disconnect()
}
```

*Disclaimer: I'm a contributor to [Kable](https://github.com/JuulLabs/kable), so this is a bit of a biased self plug.* ‍♂️